# Searching custom meta fields in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an advanced search form in my sidebar. The action is set to get_bloginfo('home') , so it should point at search.php (since the id of the form is "searchform")

That search form should filter results by custom meta fields.

I tried and created this search.php,

```
<?php
function get_reviews_by_custom_search() {
    global $wpdb;

    $grad           = preg_replace( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]/', '', $_GET['grad'] );
    $adType         = preg_replace( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]/', '', $_GET['adType'] );
    $realEstateType = preg_replace( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]/', '', $_GET['realEstateType'] );
    $dioGrada       = preg_replace( '/^[0-9a-zA-Z-]/', '', $_GET['dioGrada'] );
    $squareFrom     = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['squareFrom'] );
    $squareTo       = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['squareTo'] );
    $priceFrom      = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['priceFrom'] );
    $priceTo        = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['priceTo'] );
    $roomsNum       = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['roomsNum'] );

    // Change the defaults if not chosen
    if($squareFrom == '') { $squareFrom = '0'; }
    if($squareTo == '') { $squareTo = '10000000'; }

    // Define the arguments for the WP query
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                            'key' => 'ex_lokacija',
                            'value' => $grad ,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'ex_vrsta_oglasa',
                            'value' => $adType ,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'ex_tip_nekretnine',
                            'value' => $realEstateType ,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'ex_dio_pg',
                            'value' => $dioGrada ,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'ex_dio_pg',
                            'value' => $dioGrada ,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'et_square_footage',
                            'value' => array( $squareFrom, $squareTo ),
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'key' => 'et_price',
                            'value' => array( $priceFrom, $priceTo ),
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                                    )
            )
    );

    $searched_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    return $searched_posts;
}

$searched_posts = get_reviews_by_custom_search();       

     get_header(); ?>

        <div id="content-top">
            <div id="menu-bg"></div>
            <div id="top-index-overlay"></div>

            <div id="content" class="clearfix">
                <div id="main-area">
                    <?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs'); 

                        foreach ($searched_posts as $searched_post) {

                            echo "<h1 class=\"entry-title\"><a href=\"" . get_permalink($searched_post->ID) . "\">" . $searched_post->post_title . "</a></h1>";

                            echo "Rating - " . get_post_meta($searched_post->ID,'rating',true) . "<br>";
                            echo "Audience - " . get_post_meta($searched_post->ID,'audience',true) . "<br>";
                            echo "Length - " . get_post_meta($searched_post->ID,'length',true) . "<br>";    

                            echo "<a href=\"" . get_permalink($searched_post->ID) . "\">Read More</a>";

                        }
                    ?>

                </div> <!-- end #main-area -->

                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I found most of the code online, I'm still learning PHP.

The first part is the function that should return an array of searched posts. But, some part of the code is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It makes it easier to get good answers if you put a few lines of code that you know or suspect are wrong in your question.  Remember you can use the ` symbol (to the left of the 1 key on a QWERTY keyboard) to contain things you want to be displayed differently (like code) so they stand out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here:

1, There is a nice [Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/) you might look into

2, You could capture the search term then use it in your `WP_QUERY`:

```
$s = $_POST['search_field'];
$my_query = new WP_Query('meta_value='.$s);
```

Comment: The problem is, I have some <select> elements and radio buttons in the form. The form submits up to 7 values which i assign to variables -you can see that in the top of the file i included